# Ayuda con código scanf para un char

Tags: c, scanf

Tengo esto chicos:

```css
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

typedef enum{ELECTRICAL, CARBON, SOLAR, GASOLINE, DIESEL, MAGNETIC} tPropulsion;
typedef enum{TRUE, FALSE} boolean;
int id, year, nWagons; 
float wagonCapacity;
char model;
boolean hasLocomotive;

printf("Type the train identifier (integer) >> \n");
scanf("%d", &id);
printf("Enter the fabrication year >> ");
scanf("%d", &year);
printf("Enter the number of wagons >> ");
scanf("%d", &nWagons);
printf("Enter the wagon capacity (volume in cubic meters) >> ");
scanf("%f", &wagonCapacity);
printf("Enter the tain model (a character) >> ");
scanf(" %c", &model);

printf("Train Id: %d\n", id);
printf("Fabrication year: %d\n", year);
printf("Number of wagons: %d\n", nWagons);
printf("Wagon capacity: %f\n", wagonCapacity);
printf("Train model: %c\n", model);



}
```

Mi problema es que el char no lo lee el programa. Aparetemente todo está bien, pero no me lo lee. He probado poniendo un espacio como podéis ver, en scanf(" %c", &model); pero nada, no me lee el char.
Lo que hace el programa es que justo cuando le doy al enter en el apartado anterior (anterior scanf), me resuelve el Train model como si hubiese puesto un char. Y finaliza el programa. Es decir, me lo salta.
Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar con esto:

```
printf("Type the train identifier (integer) >> \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &id);
printf("Enter the fabrication year >> ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &year);
printf("Enter the number of wagons >> ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &nWagons);
printf("Enter the wagon capacity (volume in cubic meters) >> ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", &wagonCapacity);
printf("Enter the tain model (a character) >> ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf(" %c", &model);
```

Lo que hace el `fflush(stdin);` es limpiar el buffer de entrada del teclado antes de cada `scanf`

Comment: Al final no ha hecho falta, pero gracias por responder.

Comment: Funciona con el espacio antes de %c y poniendo en el anterior apartado el real con los decimales y un punto en vez de una coma.